# Hibernate Critria to return rows even if record does not exist LEFT OUTER JOIN

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

We have following two tables.
Item: item_id, name

ItemInfo: id, item_id, info_id, item_info

Item table can have multiple entries in ItemInfo.

I want to join above two tables at the same time I want to get the entries 
from the Item table which may not have any associated entry in ItemInfo.
How can I do achieve this with the Hibernate criteria?

```
public class Item {
    private long item_id;
    private String name;

    public long getItem_id() {
        return item_id;
    }

    public void setItem_id(long item_id) {
        this.item_id = item_id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

public class ItemInfo {
    private long id;
    private long item_id;
    private String item_info;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public long getItem_id() {
        return item_id;
    }

    public void setItem_id(long item_id) {
        this.item_id = item_id;
    }   


    public String getItem_info() {
        return item_info;
    }

    public void setItem_info(String item_info) {
        this.item_info = item_info;
    }
}
```

Comment: Show the POJOs or provide SQL.

Comment: Sorry for incorrect formatting. Above are two POJOs which I am using.

Comment: You don't need to be sorry. Rather remove your code from comments & add it to your post, by clicking on edit link given below your question.

Comment: And format the code properly in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let me correct your POJOs.

```
public class ItemInfo {
  private long id;
  private Item item_id;
  private long info_id;
  private String item_info;

 //getter-setter of all
}
```

Look for the change in datatype of item_id. Change the annotation/ mapping file accordingly.

Then try executing the following criteria.

```
Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(Item.class);
crit.setFetchMode("item_id", FetchMode.JOIN);
List<Item> itemList = criteria.list();
```

Comment: thanks RAS, I am able to fetch the records for left outer join with criteria but also I want to get the records for Item for which there would not be any entry in the corresponding Item_Info table.

Comment: Thanks RAS for the help